# How to fix this exception:Cannot convert a NSColorType.Catalog color without specifying the color space, use the overload to specify an NSColorSpace

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to build a Xamarin.Forms 5 MacOS project - the XAML is the basic as provided by the default boiler plate code.

When I compile the project I get an exception:

[image]

The exception:

> Cannot convert a NSColorType.Catalog color without specifying the color space, use the overload to specify an NSColorSpace

As I said, I have not added any custom code yet. How do I fix this?

### Update

If I downgrade to Xamarin Form 4.8 it builds and runs with no exception:

[image]

So why is 5.x failing?

---

### XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VisitsRota.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
        <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                        <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

### AppDelegate

```
using AppKit;
using Foundation;
using VisitsRota;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS;

namespace VisitsRota.MacOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        NSWindow window;
        public AppDelegate()
        {
            var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

            var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
            window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
            window.Title = "Visits Rota for Mac";
            window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
        }

        public override NSWindow MainWindow
        {
            get { return window; }
        }

        public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is on `base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);` I think.

Comment: Hi, you could select all nuget packages to update if there are other nuget packages need to be updated not only update nuget package of Xamarin Froms to check whehter it works.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have updated all packages. But I did not check the iOS and Android packages as I was only interested in MacOS.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have just performed all updates to the projects and VS and the moment I use latest version 5 it will not run.

Comment: Okey, maybe it's an issue above Xamarin Forms 5.0. I have seen that you have added it below an open [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12259). Now it seems only can downgrade the xamarin forms to make it works.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I did add a link to my question there. But in my case I have not customised the XAML in any way so was not sure if it was related, This seems fundamental to me that a boiler plate app won't execute with 5.x. I admit that my AppDelegate code is based on an example for 4.8 so maybe something is missing.

Comment: Okey, but it seems there are no differences between them for AppDelegate.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to latest Xamarin.Forms resolved this issue.